# Configuring action for UITableView custom detail disclosure button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView inside of a UIViewController. In my `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:`, I configured a cell with a custom detailDisclosure button, as follows:

```
cell.accessoryType = .detailDisclosureButton
```

I've also implemented `tableView(_:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith:)`. Using the "factory" `detailDisclosureButton` works perfectly. I don't care for the icon, so I sought to change it.

After setting the cell.accessoryType, I added the following code:

```
// declare the button
let customDetailDisclosureButton = UIButton.init(type: .detailDisclosure)

// set the image for .normal and .selected
customDetailDisclosureButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "info")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
customDetailDisclosureButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "info")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .selected)

// add a target action
customDetailDisclosureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tableView(_:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith:)), for: .touchUpInside)

cell.accessoryView = customDetailDisclosureButton
```

When I load the `tableView`, it displays fine. When I tap the detailDisclosureButton, it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the console output:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITouchesEvent length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6180000f1000'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e9ab0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001024ea141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102f0a134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e21840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e213b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x000000010425c1a0 _TTSf4g_d___TFV10Foundation9IndexPathCfT11nsIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_S0_ + 32
    6   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x0000000104210a57 _TZFV10Foundation9IndexPath36_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveCfGSqCSo11NSIndexPath_S0_ + 23
    7   MyApp                          0x0000000101e43ae7 _TToFC10MyApp22PlaylistViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView31accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithV10Foundation9IndexPath_T_ + 71
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104f17d22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010509c25c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010509c577 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010509b4b2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000105440ea9 _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 5553
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010543bec0 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1409
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010543b8f3 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 484
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010543aaba -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 274
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000104f86b9a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4092
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000104f337b0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000105716adc __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010570ea3a __handleEventQueue + 1122
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e40c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e260cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e255ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e25016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108d83a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000104f160d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    26  MyApp                          0x0000000101e4df47 main + 55
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000104dfa65d start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
```

Comment: remove customDetailDisclosureButton.addTarget line

Comment: `tableView(_:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith:)` is not compatible with a UIButton classic selector. The first parameter should be the button (sender), and not the tableView as the delegate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
// add a target action
customDetailDisclosureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tableView(_:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

with

```
customDetailDisclosureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.accessoryButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and then

```
func accessoryButtonTapped(sender : UIButton){
        let buttonPosition: CGPoint = (sender as! UIButton).convert(.zero, to: tableView)
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        // do what you gotta do with the indexPath
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to go with a "factory" solution, but this gets the job done. I added the code to get the indexPath from the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use delegate method instead of selector method :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // do you work
}
```

**OR**

Add **View** and its **Selector** method as below :

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.checkButtonTapped(_:event:)), for: .touchUpInside)
cell?.accessoryView = button
```

**Selector**

```
func checkButtonTapped(_ sender: Any, event: Any) {
    let touches: Set<AnyHashable>? = (event as AnyObject).allTouches
    let touch: UITouch? = touches?.first as! UITouch?
    let currentTouchPosition: CGPoint? = touch?.location(in: tblViewHome)
    let indexPath: IndexPath? = youtTblView?.indexPathForRow(at: currentTouchPosition!)
    if indexPath != nil {
        tableView(youtTblView!, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith: indexPath!)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented that. It works with the "factory" delegate method.

Comment: if I'm setting the accessory view in cell's "override func awakeFromNib()" method, why is the accessory view not visible?