# ios swift - UITextField.tag not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented a UITableView and all cells sharing the same UITableViewCell.swift. When I set the UITextField.tag for each cell. It is not working and returning weird result.

Could anyone help ? thanks.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddSportTableViewCell0", for: indexPath) as! AddSportTableViewCell0
        cell.dataTextField.delegate = self
        cell.dataTextField.tag = indexPath.row          
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddSportTableViewCell0", for: indexPath) as! AddSportTableViewCell0
        cell.dataTextField.delegate = self
        cell.dataTextField.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddSportTableViewCell0", for: indexPath) as! AddSportTableViewCell0
        cell.dataTextField.delegate = self
        cell.dataTextField.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddSportTableViewCell0", for: indexPath) as! AddSportTableViewCell0

        return cell
    }
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   print(textField.tag)
   return true
}
```

result: ( I only tap the first text field )

0

5

4

3

2

1

Comment: The delegate method can be called even if the text field is not starting editation.

Comment: Do not use tags to track the row. That fails miserably if your table view allows any inserts, deletes, or moves.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice @rmaddy . I have written the solution to fix the issue. What is the best practice for tracing the row?

Comment: Determine the row based on the origin of the text field.

Comment: @rmaddy could you explain more? Thanks

Comment: The two answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134699/configuring-action-for-uitableview-custom-detail-disclosure-button) show how to get the index path for a button in a cell. The code would be essentially the same. Just use the text field in your delegate method instead of the button.

Comment: Cells a queued and reused. You set the tag for a subview in a cell, but this is not guaranteed to be the same cell returned when you dequeue it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I put it to ***textFieldDidBeginEditing***(instead of ***textFieldShouldBeginEditing***), which is working as expected. Thank you all the help.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
 print(textField.tag)  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does you tableView only contain three rows? Try the below code and see if it makes any difference for you, otherwise you might have other issues with your code since your code should be working but you could make a change to improve your code though. You don´t need the switch just do it like this instead:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddSportTableViewCell0", for: indexPath) as! AddSportTableViewCell0
    cell.dataTextField.delegate = self
    cell.dataTextField.tag = indexPath.row          
    return cell
}
```

The `tag` value will be assigned to the `indexPath.row` automatically so no need for the `Switch`. This worked fine for me with the `tag` print in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

Comment: While this is a good change, how does it actually answer the question?

Comment: @rmaddy your right, I have updated the answer to be more specific. +1 for the notice.

Answer (score 1):

Write it this way:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddSportTableViewCell0", for: indexPath) as! AddSportTableViewCell0
            cell.dataTextField.delegate = self
            cell.dataTextField.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell

    }
```

Comment: While this is a good change, how does it actually answer the question?

Comment: Hey @rmaddy! Kinda assumed that the issue is with the way he wrote in cellForRowAt method. Yeah, this does not actually answer the question.